# Typescript Importing from One File Stops Reference to Another File From Working

Tags: typescript

converting project from Javascript to Typescript.

I have 3 files

- core.ts - A core library of functions and a global variable that holds application state.
- keyboards.ts - Holds functions pertaining to virtual keyboards
- floorplan.ts - Holds functions pertaining to a floorplan map with KonvaJS.

None of these files are modules. That will come once they're refactored significantly.

core.js has a global variable `application` which holds state data. This is populated on initialization.

```
interface ApplicationState {
    keyboard: keyboard
    mode: string
    floorplan: floorplan
    languageVars: Record<string, string>
}

let application: ApplicationState = {
    keyboard : null,
    mode: "default",
    floorplan: null,
    languageVars: {}
}
```

In keyboards.ts I define an interface:

```
/// <reference path="core.ts" />
interface keyboard {
    capsLock: boolean
    shift: boolean
    layout: string
}
```

Now as you can see, core.ts has an interface (ApplicationState) that requires a member of type `keyboard` which is not defined until keyboard.ts. This actually works fine.

In floorplan.ts, I have another interface

```
///<reference path="core.ts"/>
import Konva from "../konva/lib/index-types";
interface floorplan {
    stage: Konva.Stage,
    transformer: Konva.Transformer,
    tableLayer: Konva.Layer,
    activeTableNumbers: number[],
    activeTables: table[],
    basis: 1280,
    scale: number,
    newTable: table[],
    currentRoom: room
}
```

However if I try to modify the ApplicationState interface to include `floorplan: floorplan` then I get the error `Cannot find name 'floorplan'`

So if do `export interface floorplan` in floorplan.ts and in core.ts do
`import {floorplan} from './floorplan'`

Then that works as expected but then any reference to `application` in keyboards.ts stops working (`Cannot find name 'application').

Is there a correct way to be doing this?

Comment: import all the contents of a file by using ‘import *’ `import * as {floorplan} from './floorplan'`

Comment: That still breaks the keyboard.ts file. Should I be importing application from in there too?